# Managing permissions method in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, user-permissions, symfony-security

I'm creating a Symfony2 website that has users and each user can have multiple permissions like this:

```
User1: manage users , manage sales , manage repository
User2: manage repository
user3: manage sales , manage repository
...
```

for such a system what is the correct permission system to use?
**`Roles` or `ACLs` or `voters` or something else?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Roles

Roles are OK if you want to grant *"general"* permissions.

For example, if you need user to be able to manage **all** or users, then you can create a role for it, for example `ROLE_USER_MANAGER`. Or if you want to grant him rights to manage sales, you can grant him `ROLE_SALES_MANAGER` role.

So basically, use **Roles** when you have **limited number of permissions** to some **entities generally**.

You **can** use them for other stuff by granting roles that contain entity names and ids for example, `ROLE_MANAGER_REPOSITORY_23` and then using custom voters you can know that users with that role can manage repository with id 23. Even though this approach can work, I personally don't like it.

#### ACL

If you have a lot of dynamic permission granting, especially towards individual models, then ACL is the way to go. It is *usually* a bit less performant, as it needs to fetch more data from the data store, but is a lot more suitable for this purpose.

With [**Symfony2** ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html), it's incredibly easy to grant and check permissions, and even to allow individual users to grant permissions to each other.

Furthermore, introduction part of [Symfony ACL docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) shows you both of these approaches and also point out some ups/downs for each.